# Why am I getting an "Expected: End of Statement" error?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, report

I've used this code before to set the Report Filter in Excel, but for some reason I now keep getting an "Expected: End of Statement", highlighting "CurrentPage"

```
Sheets("Template").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields ("Company_Name") _
         CurrentPage = Sheets("Template").Range("E1").Text
```

Answer (score 1):

The underscore is the line-continuation character. Your statement should be on two different lines, and always precede the underscore with a space - I know you are doing this already, but I mention this for anyone else reading:

```
Sheets("Template").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Company_Name") _ 
   CurrentPage = Sheets("Template").Range("E1").Text
```

However, `CurrentPage` is a property of the `PivotField`, so you are missing the dot at the beginning of the second line:

```
Sheets("Template").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Company_Name") _ 
   .CurrentPage = Sheets("Template").Range("E1").Text
```

Comment: Ok, so I now have the following all on one line: 'Sheets("Template").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Company Name").CurrentPage = Sheets("Template").Range("E1").Text', but I'm getting a generic 1004 error....I know for a fact that the sheet name, pivot table name, and field name are correct...

Comment: You've dropped the underscore between Company and Name.